# Oracle SQL: looking at pump run durations; displaying a result if any pump has not run for more than 28 days

Tags: sql, oracle

First post so please bear with me!

I need to create a report which whether the duration between pump operation exceeds 28 days

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  FR.DESCRIPTION "FOR NAME",
  DIG.DB "DB ADDR",
  PNT."NAME" "SIGNAL NAME",
  DIG.CHOSEN_VALUE_TEXT "TEXT PAIR",
  DIG.CHOSEN_VALUE_NUM "BOOLEAN",
  DIG.DATE_TIME,
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM DIG.DATE_TIME - LAG(DIG.DATE_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY DIG.DB ORDER BY DIG.DATE_TIME)) "Duration",
  CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM DIG.DATE_TIME - LAG(DIG.DATE_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY DIG.DB ORDER BY DIG.DATE_TIME))>30 THEN 'RED' 
   WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM DIG.DATE_TIME - LAG(DIG.DATE_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY DIG.DB ORDER BY DIG.DATE_TIME))BETWEEN 28 AND 30 THEN 'AMBER'
   ELSE 'GREEN'
  END "RAG_STATUS"
FROM
  DATA_DIGITALVALUES DIG
JOIN
  POINT PNT ON DIG.DB = CONCAT('1:',PNT.DB)
JOIN
   FOR FR ON PNT.FOR = FR.ID
WHERE
  (PNT."NAME" LIKE '%Pump%' AND PNT."NAME" LIKE '%Status%')
AND
  DIG.DATE_TIME>= (SYSDATE-70)
AND
EXTRACT(DAY FROM DIG.DATE_TIME - LAG(DIG.DATE_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY DIG.DB_IDENT ORDER BY DIG.DATE_TIME) > 28

ORDER BY
  FR.DESCRIPTION,PNT.NAME,DIG.DATE_TIME
```

I can get the main body of data OK, but I'm trying to reduce the number of rows as my query normally looks back one year, but stating either that the difference between the timestamp and the lag timestamp is >28 or that the Rag status = Amber or Red

I tried adding in the day extraction in as a where clause but I keep getting the ***"Windows functions are not allowed here"*** error.

If someone can advise please how to return only rows with a duration of greater than 28.

Many thanks
Ian

Comment: Hi Ian, - Not bad for a first post! It would help to describe your base tables a little bit (only the relevant columns, including their data type especially for dates and timestamps), and a small sample of data. Then the exact form of the desired output. We shouldn't have to "understand" those from your code, you should state them explicitly. Question: When there is a gap of more than 28 days, which rows exactly do you need returned? You say rows with a duration of... but rows themselves don't have duration, they have gap to lag(row...).

Comment: I don't understand your logic fully so can't suggest you a query but first you don't need to extract day, you can just subtract two dates and result is number of days. Second I would think about self join instead of using lag and cut off uneeded results on join condition. If you can describe table structures and relations more this may make question easier to answer.
And as mathguy said. It's not bad as for first post

Comment: Just a note, your would never be "GREEN" because you select only `WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM DIG.DATE_TIME ... ) > 28`

Comment: Another note `EXTRACT(DAY FROM ...)` will extract **only** the number of days, i.e. the interval could be several months or even years but you still get numbers below 31.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work

```
WITH t AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT
    FR.DESCRIPTION "FOR NAME",
    DIG.DB "DB ADDR",
    PNT."NAME" "SIGNAL NAME",
    DIG.CHOSEN_VALUE_TEXT "TEXT PAIR",
    DIG.CHOSEN_VALUE_NUM "BOOLEAN",
    DIG.DATE_TIME,
    DIG.DATE_TIME - LAG(DIG.DATE_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY DIG.DB ORDER BY DIG.DATE_TIME) "Duration"
  FROM
    DATA_DIGITALVALUES DIG
  JOIN
    POINT PNT ON DIG.DB = CONCAT('1:',PNT.DB)
  JOIN
    FOR FR ON PNT.FOR = FR.ID
  WHERE
    (PNT."NAME" LIKE '%Pump%' AND PNT."NAME" LIKE '%Status%')
  AND
    DIG.DATE_TIME>= (SYSDATE-70))
SELECT t.*,
CASE 
   WHEN "Duration" > INTERVAL '30' DAY THEN 'RED'
   WHEN "Duration" BETWEEN INTERVAL '28' DAY AND INTERVAL '30' DAY THEN 'AMBER'
  ELSE 'GREEN'
END AS RAG_STATUS
FROM t
WHERE "Duration" > INTERVAL '28' DAY;
```

As already stated in comment `ELSE 'GREEN'` does not make much sense if you have condition `WHERE "Duration" > INTERVAL '28' DAY`. Anyway, I assume you get an idea how to solve your problem.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for your help, this works perfectly.